# Why I get unexpected end of file in my script when using gzip?

Tags: scripting, gzip

I have one doubt with this:

```
for i in ./*.gz
do
gunzip -c $i | head -8000 | gzip > $(basename $i)
done
```

I get an "unexpected end of file" error for gzip, and I don't get the 8000 at all, only a few tens of lines. I've checked the integrity of my files and they are fine. Curiously, if I run for individual files:

```
gunzip -c file1.gz | head -8000 | gzip > file1.gz
```

I get the expected result. With this script I can obtain the first 8000 lines from a compressed file with 10708712 lines, and compress again. The new file overwrites the original file, but that's ok.

Comment: If the individual invocation worked for you you just got lucky. Redirecting back into a file that you're reading is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write the output to a temporary file and then rename:

```
for i in ./*.gz 
do 
  gunzip -c "$i" | head -8000 | gzip > "$i.tmp"
  mv -f "$i.tmp" $(basename "$i") 
done
```

That your version sometimes works is if you `gunzip` buffers enough while reading.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I only add the option `-f` to `mv`

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I added the -f to the script (for those that don't make it to the comments ;-) )